# how can i use re.search to find all the words end with 'ly' and 'ed'

Tags: python

text = "He was carefully disguised but captured quickly by police."
import re

def re_search(pattern):

```
result, start = [], 0
#insert your code begin
length = len(text)
pattern1 = re.compile(pattern)
while start < length:
    matchresult1 = pattern1.search(text,start)
    all = matchresult1.group(0)
    s = matchresult1.start()
    e = matchresult1.end()
    result.append((all,s,e))
    start = e  
    if not matchresult1:
        break     
return result
```

pattern = r'(\w+)(ly|ed)'
re_search(pattern)

what i expected is expected = [('carefully', 7, 16), ('disguised', 17, 26), ('captured', 31, 39)，('quickly', 40, 47)]

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work as you never return the result. Please post the actual code you have, and describe what you see and what you expected to see.

Comment: what i expected is expected = [('carefully', 7, 16), ('disguised', 17, 26), ('captured', 31, 39)，('quickly', 40, 47)]

Comment: it says 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: So that means `matchresult1` is `None`, thus `search()` failed, so would it not be better to do `if not matchresult1: break` much earlier?

Answer (score 0):

The python re module has finditer function ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer ) which gives an iterator yielding match objects.

```
for match in re.finditer(pattern, text): 
    print(match)
```

output:                                                                                                          `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(7, 16), match='carefully'>`
`<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(17, 26), match='disguised'>`
`<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(31, 39), match='captured'>`
`<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(40, 47), match='quickly'>`

Comment: Then basically you have to an iterator using re.search(). So, run re.search and yield the match if there is a match and look run the search on the remaining string.